# would I still use addListenerForSingleValueEvent to retrieve multiple results

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was thinking to query a whole table. I'm querying from my firebase database. what got me confused was it says `ForSingleValueEvent` is there something that I am not getting here?

```
Query query = reference
                    .child(getString(R.string.Lobby_table))
                    .orderByChild(getString(R.string.Lobby_lobbyname))
                    .equalTo(search);

            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent();
```

Comment: Did you check [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) for Firebase data event listeners? And your question is quite confusing. _"is there something that I am not getting here?"_ What do you want to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attaching a listener with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` it retrieves **all matching data** for the query/reference once, and then stops listening.

So if there are three lobbies starting with the `search` term, you will get all three passed into `onDataSnapshot`. But if later a fourth lobby is added that matches, you won't get notified of that until you add a new listener.